# How are functions modified at run-time then propagated to multiple threads?

Tags: function, concurrency, clojure

With Clojure (and other Lisp dialects) you can modify running code. So, when a function is modified during runtime is that change made available to multiple threads?

I'm trying to figure out how it works technically in a concurrent setting: if several threads are using a function *foo*, what happens when I redefine (say using *defn*) the function *foo*?

There has to be some synchronization going on: when and how does such synchronization happen and what does it cost?

Say on a JVM, is the function referenced using a `volatile` reference?  If so, does it mean every single time there's a "function lookup" then one has to pay the `volatile` cost?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Clojure functions are instances of the `IFn` class and they [are almost always stored in `vars`](http://clojure.org/vars). vars are Clojures mechanism for **thread local values**.

- when you define a function that sets the "root binding" of the var to reference the function
- threads other threads get whatever the the current value of the root binding for the var but can't change the value. this prevents any two threads from having to fight over the value of the var because only the root thread can set the value.
- threads can choose to use a new value of the var if they need to, but calling `binding` which gives then their own **thread local value** that they are free to change at will because no other thread can read it.

A good understanding of vars is well worth a little study, they are a very useful concurrency device once you get used to them.

ps: the root thread is usually the REPL
pss: you are of course free to store your functions in something other than vars, if for instance you needed to atomically update a group of functions, though this is rare.

Comment: +1 and thanks for being always so helpful regarding Clojure (and other topics ; )      Is your first point a sentence or where the first two points supposed to be merged together in one paragraph?  I think you meant to write something a bit different : )

Comment: @cedric Martin, I'll give that one another pass though the grammar machine... ;-)